# Custom authentication with GoogleProvider In Next-Auth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am trying to create an application using NextJS and Next-Auth, I want if they use Google Sign In method, I can add a custom authentication method like in CredentialsProvider so we can create an account for the user in the database, I am using Prisma, thanks in advance.

```
providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    })
  ]
```

Comment: What exactly do you want, GoogleProvider or CredentialsProvider ?